# Understand cyclotron motion in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields

It is well-known that a charged particle in classical mechanics performs a circular motion in a homogeneous magnetic field.

I would like to understand how this effect can be described in the quantum setting. Clearly, a charged particle in a magnetic field is described by the Landau levels, but is there any trace of the circular orbits in that theory?

Perhaps, what expectation value would I have to analyze to make the circular orbits appear?

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Expectation value of an observable resembles classical motion

Comment: @K_inverse not quite: Landau levels have a high degeneracy, and the usually-found wavefunctions corresponding to them don't actually resemble the circular motion in any way. One has to combine the degenerate eigenstates in a particular way to recover something that makes sense classically.

Comment: a google search brings a number of entries,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPMde3zBgNo       page 25 here http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/lec5_compressed.pdf